# Como suspender o parâmetro $_GET se o array estiver vazio?

Tags: php, html

Este parâmetro `tipo[]` é enviado para a url mesmo que ele esteja vazio. Existe uma forma de não enviar este parâmetro se nenhum valor foi selecionado?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="APARTAMENTO/APTO DUPLEX" id="tp1">
<label for="tp1">Apartamento</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="CASA" id="tp2">
<label for="tp2">Casa</label>

<input type="checkbox" name="tipo[]" value="CASA EM CONDOMINIO" id="tp3">
<label for="tp3">Casa Condomínio</label>
```

Answer (score 3):

O código da página está no lado do cliente, ou seja, está no navegador e não no servidor.

Assim sendo, via PHP não tens como controlar o que vai ou não vai para o URL com base no seu preenchimento ou não preenchimento.

Se pretendes excluir do URL determinados parâmetros que por sua vez são campos de um formulário submetido com o método *GET*, terás que fazer uso de JavaScript.

## jQuery

```js
// Anexar código à submissão do formulário
$('#idDoMeuFormulario').submit(function(){

  // desativar elementos sem valor
  $('#idDoMeuFormulario :input[value=""]').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Pelas normas, os elementos `disabled` não são enviados com a submissão do formulário.

Isto dá-nos um controlo eficaz sobre o que vai ou não vai ser enviado. No exemplo em cima estamos a selecionar todos os elementos vazios e a desativar os mesmos para que não sejam enviados ao submeter o formulário.

### O teu caso

No teu caso, parece que pretendes excluir `checkbox` não marcadas, então podes:

```js
// Anexar código à submissão do formulário
$('#idDoMeuFormulario').submit(function(){

  // desativar caixas de seleção não marcadas
  $('#idDoMeuFormulario input:checkbox:not(:checked)').attr('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode bloquear o envio do form caso o valor esteja vazio.
Pode ser via javascript ou por HTML5 colocando a tag 'required'

Caso contrário, você tem que realizar a verificação desses valores no backend.

No caso do PHP você pode montar uma verificação simples do $_GET da seguinte forma:

```
if(!empty($_GET["tipo"])){
    $tipo = $_GET["tipo"];
}
```

Segue documentação para consulta.

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Explique pra ele como fazer.

Comment: Eu não posso bloquear o formulário pois ele envia vários parâmetros e um deles sempre será retornará um valor. Tenho uma `URL` gigante com parâmetros sem valores, gostaria de evitar isto.

Comment: Marcos, eu complementei a resposta, com um exemplo de código para validar o $_GET.

Qualquer dúvida estamos ai!

Comment: Raphael, qual seria procedimento com `selects`?

Comment: @RaphaelRamos porque usar o `array_key_exists` ao invés de `isset`?

Comment: Raphael, esse `if($_GET['var'])` vai gerar uma `notice` no PHP, não?... creio que a resposta foi marcada como correta por causa do `array_key_exists`...

Comment: @gmsantos, nunca tinha visto também, mas parece uma alternativa válida... creio ter visto alguma variante com `in_array` + `array_key_exists`.

Comment: Na verdade @MarcosVinicius, ambos não irão funcionar. Pois dentro da variavel $_GET a chave 'tipo' está setada.

Tanto o isset() e o array_key_exists verificam a existência da chave. No caso, teremos que usar a função empty().

Alterei o exemplo.

Comment: @gmsantos usar apenas o if($_GET['var']) também funciona. O PHP converte os valores para boleanos.
Porém, ele considera uma string vazia como um valor True.

Diferente de quando você tem um int = 0.

O if de um inteiro vazio é considerado false pelo PHP. Assim como variáveis com o valor NULL

Comment: @RaphaelRamos a diferença do `isset` e `array_key_exists` é que o `isset` verifica somente o conteúdo da chave. Caso a chave tenha um valor `null`, o `isset` retorna false. Já o `array_key_exists` verifica a chave, independente do valor. No seu exemplo recomendo o `isset`, pois o que importa é o valor da chave, não se ela existe.

Comment: @gmsantos. exatamente!
O problema é que o rapaz está validando um GET. E de qualquer jeito virá existirá o $_GET['tipo'].
No caso do usuário não preencher esse campo ele virá como string vazia. O que para o PHP é diferente de NULL.
O isset considera uma string vazia como true.

Por isso eu recomendo o uso do empty() no lugar do isset().

Answer (score 1):

Não enviar: O correto seria usar javascript para **não enviar** ao servidor.

Porém o seu servidor de qualquer forma estará esperando por um valor, mesmo que seja 'nada' (null), e ao enviar nulo, não precisa mais de javascript para cancelar;

O ideal é você verificar no PHP se o valor foi setado ou não.

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['tipo']))
{
    echo "Recebi algum valor na variável TIPO via GET.<br>";

    $tipos = $_GET['tipo'];
    foreach ($tipos as $v) 
    {
        echo "$v<br>";
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Não recebi nada na variável TIPO via GET.<br>";    
}

?>
```

Comment: o isset não irá funcionar nesse caso.
Pois o $_GET['tipo'] vem como string vazia.
E a função isset() irá retornar TRUE.

Comment: Eu acabei de testar para verificar, é nula sim. A variável não é enviada via GET. att